# Blazor WebAssembly Dotnet 5 Javascript Interop can't find JS function

Tags: javascript, .net-core, blazor-webassembly

I am getting this error while trying to run JS in Blazor WA dotnet 6:

> Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: Could not find 'bweInterop.getWindowSize' ('bweInterop' was undefined).
> Error: Could not find 'bweInterop.getWindowSize' ('bweInterop' was undefined).

My `index.razor` is:

```cs
    @page "/"
    @using BwaJsInterop.Model
    @inject IJSRuntime Js
    <PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>
    @if (_windowSize.Width != null)
    {
        <h2>
            Window Size: @_windowSize.Width x @_windowSize.Height
        </h2>
    }
    <button @onclick="GetWindowSize">Get Window Size</button>
    @code {
        private WindowSize _windowSize = new();
        private async Task GetWindowSize()
        {
            _windowSize = await Js.InvokeAsync<WindowSize>(
                "bweInterop.getWindowSize");
        }
    }
```

I placed the external javascript in the wwwroot/index.js:

```html
<body>
    <div id="app">Loading...</div>

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        An unhandled error has occurred.
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bweInterop.js"></script> 
</body>
```

Javascript is located here:

[image]

And finally the javascript file itself:

```js
let bweInterop = {};
bweInterop.getWindowSize = function () {
    return {
        width: window.innerWidth,
        height: window.innerHeight
    };
}
```

In the browser console, I ran `bweInterop.getWindowSize()` function and it works, so the problem is not the javascript.

[image]

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you're running into issues with Blazor's JavaScript module isolation ([see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-7.0#javascript-isolation-in-javascript-modules)). Try explicitly loading your JS file inside your Blazor component, i. e.:

```
@page "/"
@using BwaJsInterop.Model
@inject IJSRuntime Js
<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>
@if (_windowSize.Width != null)
{
    <h2>
        Window Size: @_windowSize.Width x @_windowSize.Height
    </h2>
}
<button @onclick="GetWindowSize">Get Window Size</button>
@code {
    private WindowSize _windowSize = new();
    private IJSObjectReference? module;

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            module = await Js.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./js/bweInterop.js");
        }
    }

    private async Task GetWindowSize()
    {
        _windowSize = await module.InvokeAsync<WindowSize>(
            "bweInterop.getWindowSize");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks mu88! You led me to the right direction, the code you provided is correct but there was one more thing that I was missing. I didn't know that I had to do this, but in the javascript side I needed to export the function first. `export function getWindowSize () { ... }`. With your answer and the link you provided I was able to get this working. Thank you very much!